# Baby rudin 8.21

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, gamma-function, change-of-variable, beta-function

[image]Things to remark before 8.21.

$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt. $

If $x>0$ and $y > 0$ , then $\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt $ = $\frac {\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ = $B(x,y)$. ( Mark this equality by $(a)$)
The substitution $t$ = $\sin^2(\theta)$ turns $(a)$ into

$2\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2} } (\sin\theta)^{2x-1} (\cos\theta)^{2y-1}d\theta$ = $B(x,y)$.

I don't understand how did we get that?
$\frac {dt}{d\theta} $ = $2\sin\theta\cos\theta$

don't we should have $(\cos\theta)^{3y-1}$ instead of $(\cos\theta)^{2y-1}$ ?

I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Double check the exponents. It wouldn’t be just $-1$ if we made the substitution without the $d\theta$ being correct. (This is also why the coefficient of $2$ appears in front.)

Comment: @Clayton I didn't get what you  say.

Comment: Take $t^{x-1}$ for example. Replacing $t$ with $\sin^2\theta$ yields $(\sin\theta)^{2x-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $t=\sin^2\theta$, you have
$$t^{x-1}=\left(\sin^2\theta\right)^{x-1}=\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2(x-1)}=\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2x-2}\\
\left(1-t\right)^{y-1}=\left(1-\sin^2\theta\right)^{y-1}=\left(\cos^2\theta\right)^{y-1}=\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2(y-1)}=\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2y-2}\\ dt=2\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta$$
Now do the substitution in the integral for $B(x,y)$:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2x-2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2y-2}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta=
2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2x-2+1}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2y-2+1}\,d\theta\\
=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2x-1}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2y-1}\,d\theta$$